# How to show xml file in mvc View?

Tags: html, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have xml file with .xls style. How Can I display it on my mvc view (razor)?

Localization file: `@"D:\Result22.xml"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(input);
```

If you prefer you can instead make the content type change from your view action, like so

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
          Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
          return View();
 }
```

OR

You can use an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) to convert your XML into XHTML and then display that.